# Z-index not working as expected working with picture and background-div

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have a image, and I'd like to have an effect on my page where a background-div with gray color is displayed 5px on the left side and bottom of the picture. But for some reason, I can't get the background-div to align behind the picture. It always lays ontop. How can I fix this?

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3Z7m4/2/

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Add `position: relative;` into the `img` CSS.

See: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

> Note: z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute,
>   position:relative, or position:fixed).

Comment: That worked. Thanks. Also, I find this prettier than the other answer posted. Now my z-indexes are read correctly.

Comment: See the reference I added, the z-index only works when `position` is given. That's why the `img` tags z-index was not working.

Comment: Ah, okey. I sat relative on the parent-div, I thought that was enough. Thanks for reference, I'll take a look at that!

Answer (score 2):

just try,

```
.container .gray {
    width: 420px;
    height: 315px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: -315px;
    z-index: -10;
    background-color: gray;
}
```

Comment: Crap...that was easy. Worked in all browsers. Thanks. But what is the logic behind this? My picture's z-index is higher than the background. Does not make sense. Anyways, case closed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: See my answer for the correct way to fix this. The `img` tags z-index is discarded because no `position` was given. By setting `.gray`s z-index to negative works too because gray does have the `position` specified and in this puts the `.gray` behind your `img`.