# Uncovering Logo - Blocked by Background Image from Another DIV

Tags: html, css

At this link, you can see the bottom of the logo is blocked by the background image in the next DIV going down the page.  I thought z-index was supposed to control this, but I am stumped.
http://dansdemos.info/prototypes/htmlSamples/responsive/step15_LogoProb.html

Is there a good way to put the logo where it goes on this page?

Any assistance will be extremely much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: [Z-index not working as expected working with picture and background-div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8136655/z-index-not-working-as-expected-working-with-picture-and-background-div)

It may be that you need to set the logo to `position: relative` in order for z-index to work.

Answer (score 0):

if you set the logo:

```
position: absolute
```

or

```
position: relative
```

that will work, its weird but that works.  now the thing is that with position absolute you have to set the left or rights..

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfect.  Really appreciate the help.  Tried voting this up, but I don't have the points required.  I am not sure what the protocol is for thanking people or indicating that I got an answer.  Thanks again!   I made the change and the logo stacks right now, visible at this link.  http://dansdemos.info/prototypes/htmlSamples/responsive/step15_LogoProb.html